# Perform Segue In Custom UICollectionView Embedded in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a UITableView that has custom cells which includes a UICollectionView that scrolls horizontally, something like the Netflix app. I'm trying to perform a segue whenever the user clicks on the UICollectionViewCell. However, `performSegue(withIdentifier: )` isn't available in Collection View Cells.

[image]

I tried using a delegate to handle the segue as so:

In my view controller class:

```
func segueToNext(identifier: String) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: identifier, sender: self)
    }
```

In the UITableViewCell class, I have the Collection View delegate methods, and I have this code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    delegate?.segueToNext(identifier: "showDiningServices")
}
```

`segueToNext` isn't called when I clicked on the cell. Are there other ways to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you assigned the delegate ?

Comment: Is delegate nil ? Who is the delegate exactly ? The UIViewController or the UITableViewCell ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the VC

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = //////
   cell.delegate = self
}
```

//

for this to work you have to set

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    delegate?.segueToNext(identifier: "showDiningServices")
}
```

//

```
self.collectionView.delegate = self // self here is UITableViewCell
```

**OR**

You can also implement collectionView delegate and dataSource inside the VC like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = //////
   cell.collectionView.delegate = self
   cell.collectionView.dataSource = self
}
```

then directly implement this inside the VC

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDiningServices", sender: self)  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to push a view controller using navigation controller(using method pushViewController).When a user clicks on a collection view cell than collection view delegate didSelectItemAtIndexPath is called and you can perform pushing of view controller in that delegate method.